# UNION 3 Tables that do not all contain the same attributes

Tags: sql, oracle

I've spent many hours on this and cannot figure out how to do this.

The problem is:

"Use UNION to list the vendors supplying a line item containing ‘MVS’ or ‘VSAM’. Include the vendor ID and name."

Here are the specs relevant to each table.

- VENDORS table contains attributes VENDOR_ID and VENDOR_NAME.
- INVOICES table contains attributes VENDOR_ID and INVOICE_ID.
- INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS table contains attributes INVOICE_ID and LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTIONS

My code, I've tried many things.

```
SELECT VENDOR_ID, VENDOR_NAME, TO_NUMBER(NULL) INVOICE_ID,
       TO_CHAR(NULL) LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
FROM VENDORS
UNION
SELECT VENDOR_ID, TO_CHAR(NULL) VENDOR_NAME, INVOICE_ID,
       TO_CHAR(NULL) LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
FROM INVOICES
UNION
SELECT TO_NUMBER(NULL) VENDOR_ID, TO_CHAR(NULL) VENDOR_NAME, INVOICE_ID,
      LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION
FROM INVOICE_LINE_ITEMS
WHERE INSTR(LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'MVS') > 0 OR
      INSTR(LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 'VSAM') > 0;
```

This is producing 239 lines of output. If I were using JOIN, I would get 3 lines of output. My output has so many null spaces because of the TO_CHAR() and TO_NUMBER() functions.

Example Output (I took bits and pieces so you could see how spread out the four columns are)

```
VENDOR_ID VENDOR_NAME                       INVOICE_ID LINE_ITEM_DESCRIPTION        
       34                                            2                                
       35 Cal State Termite                                                                            
       36 Graylift                                                                                     
       37 Blue Cross                                                                                   
       37                                           69                                
       37                                          111                                
       37                                          112                                
       38 Venture Communications Int'l                                                                 
       39 Custom Printing Company
                                                     1 MVS Online Library             
                                                     4 MVS JCL                        
                                                    34 VSAM for the Cobol Prog
```

Comment: When you're using UNION, oracle is going to fetch the results of all the separate queries and join the results into a single resultset. When you're using a join, oracle is going to join the tables and fetch the resultset that matches the criteria in all the tables. In order to get all the results irrespective of matching them using a join, you need to look into using OUTER JOIN.

Comment: @Shankar Unfortunately, my professor requires us to use UNION on this problem. I've been able to solve this using JOIN.  I just don't see a way to make it appear combined only using UNION. It appears to be impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see it making any sense to require a union is if your professor meant for you to implement the `or` condition with one; which is still odd, but at least possible:

```
select v.vendor_id, v.vendor_name
from vendors v
join invoices i on i.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
join invoice_line_items ili on ili.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
where ili.line_item_description like '%MVS%'
union
select v.vendor_id, v.vendor_name
from vendors v
join invoices i on i.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
join invoice_line_items ili on ili.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
where ili.line_item_description like '%VSAM%'
```

Or you could union the line items in an inline view or CTE and join from that, which is probably slightly more efficient, and perhaps sounds slightly closer to how the assignment was phrased:

```
select v.vendor_id, v.vendor_name
from (
  select invoice_id
  from invoice_line_items
  where item_description like '%MVS%'
  union
  select invoice_id
  from invoice_line_items
  where item_description like '%VSAM%'
) ili
join invoices i on i.invoice_id = ili.invoice_id
join vendors v on v.vendor_id = i.vendor_id
```

Or maybe you professor is just messing with you.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment says to use union. It doesn't say you should avoid join. 
So make a union of two sql statements, listing 'MVS' and 'VSAM' separately.  While suited for the daily wtf, it should fit the assignment description.